# Using norwegian letters æøå in python

Tags: python, utf-8

I'm learning python and PyGTK now, and have created a simple Music Organizer.
http://pastebin.com/m2b596852
But when it edits songs with the Norwegian letters æ, ø, and å it's just changing them to a weird character.

So is there any good way of opening or encode the names into utf-8 characters?

#### Two relevant places from the above code:

Read info from a file:

```
def __parse(self, filename):
    "parse ID3v1.0 tags from MP3 file"
    self.clear()
    self['artist'] = 'Unknown'
    self['title'] = 'Unknown'
    try:
        fsock = open(filename, "rb", 0)
        try:
            fsock.seek(-128, 2)
            tagdata = fsock.read(128)
        finally:
            fsock.close()
        if tagdata[:3] == 'TAG':
            for tag, (start, end, parseFunc) in self.tagDataMap.items():
                self[tag] = parseFunc(tagdata[start:end])
    except IOError:
        pass
```

Print to sys.stdout info:

```
for info in files:
    try:
        os.rename(info['name'], 
            os.path.join(self.dir, info['artist'])+' - '+info['title']+'.mp3')

        print 'From: '+ info['name'].replace(os.path.join(self.dir, ''), '')
        print 'To:   '+ info['artist'] +' - '+info['title']+'.mp3'
        print
        self.progressbar.set_fraction(i/num)
        self.progressbar.set_text('File %d of %d' % (i, num))
        i += 1
    except IOError:
        print 'Rename fail'
```

Comment: What error is produced by `tagdata[start:end].decode("utf-8")`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want to start by decoding the input FROM the charset it is in TO utf-8 (in Python, encode means "take it from unicode/utf-8 to some other charset").

Some googling suggests the Norwegian charset is plain-ole 'iso-8859-1'... I hope someone can correct me if I'm wrong on this detail. Regardless, whatever the name of the charset in the following example:

```
tagdata[start:end].decode('iso-8859-1')
```

In a real-world app, I realize you can't guarantee that the input is norwegian, or any other charset. In this case, you will probably want to proceed through a series of likely charsets to see which you can convert successfully. Both SO and Google have some suggestions on algorithms for doing this effectively in Python. It sounds scarier than it really is.

Comment: Glad it works. For my own curiosity, since I see from your profile that you are in Norway, is the Norwegian character set in fact covered by ISO-8859-1?

Comment: The Norwegian charset is indeed covered by ISO-8859-1.

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to convert the bytestrings you read from the file into Unicode character strings. Looking at your code, I would do this in the parsing function, i.e. replace `stripnulls` with something like this

```
def stripnulls_and_decode(data):
    return codecs.utf_8_decode(data.replace("\00", "")).strip()
```

Note that this will only work if the strings in the file are in fact encoded in UTF-8 - if they're in a different encoding, you'd have to use the corresponding decoding function from the `codecs` module.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what encodings are used for mp3 tags but if you are sure that it is UTF-8 then:

```
 tagdata[start:end].decode("utf-8")
```

The line `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` defines your source code encoding and doesn't define encoding used to read from or write to files.

Comment: Just as some added information, you could use `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` if you were to use Norwegian characters within your code, such as `artist_name = 'Bjørn Eidsvåg'`.

Answer (score 1):

In Python3 I solved my string problem the following way:

```
'random string pÃ¤ivitÃ¤n'.encode("latin-1").decode("utf-8")
```

This gave me the desired scandinavian vocals.